# How to run on background?

Tags: android-intent, android

I'm write a chatting application on android. How to show notification when the application has been closed?

please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your application should include a service running in the background to check for new received messages. In case there's a new message, that service could show a notificaiton to the user.

Comment: Yeap, how to a service running in the background?

Comment: Here's the tutorial about services: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html